Interfacing external PHY(Microchip KSZ9477 PHY) with Raspberry Pi/Pico
I want to use an External Phy as i need hardware time stamping at PHY level for PTP packets, KSZ9477 does the trick but i am little skeptical regarding the effort needed to interface it with Broadcom's MAC. Does someone know how i can interface an External Phy with a Raspberry Pi board with RGMII connection? KSZ9477 Phy can connected to ethernet mac only with RGMII. So far i dont find any reliable documentation regarding how i could do this, considering also that Broadcoms documentation is very limited.

See Tour to see how this site works
and How do I ask a good question?
